# Crashing In Lobby With Friend

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm trying to play CSGO with a friend, but whenever she joins the lobby, after a few seconds my game freezes, audio and all. If I click, the game just crashes, but if my friend leaves then the game resumes as normal. We were playing fine a week ago.

I googled it and other people have had similar problems, but not the same. Most had their game fully crash along with their steam client. They also couldn't find a solution other than some "Killer Network Driver" from their motherboard, but I have made no hardware or driver changes, and I've been using this motherboard for a few years now.

Comment: A driver update never hurts. Also, are you on the same local network?

Comment: I've tried driver updates and rollbacks, and yes, we're on the same LAN.

Comment: Have you tried verifying your game files or reinstalling CSGO?

Comment: I tried verifying the files, a re-install is not worth the hassle unless there is a way to export all of your settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it's something to do with voice chat after all.

When my friend turns voice chat off, it works fine. She doesn't even need to leave, it just unfreezes as soon as she disables it.

I noticed something extra, too. After unfreezing, I checked the console and got some kind of looping error. I can't quite remember what it was (something to do with Voice Channel 0) so I'll update this when I next play and see it.